# good ticket system for managing a hardware/software platform?

Tags: untagged

What would be a good system for managing a visualization service?

This platform is made of hardware components (a video conferencing system, a number of displays, a rendering cluster, an optical tracking system...) and software components, both developed in-house and COTS.

It takes up a whole room and has to be booked.

The needs I identified (for now) are:

- a calendar for reservations
- trouble tickets
- possibly a bug tracking system for the in-house software components (at least the ones that do not require being developed on a full-fledged forge, such as deployment scripts or configuration files...) and for submitting RFEs.
- a knowledge base / documentation system

Ideally, we would use the same software to manage scheduled and unscheduled maintenance operations, and keep the users informed of those.

An open source solution would be preferred. I have some experience with RT, which (AFAIK) only covers part of those needs and seems a little heavy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source [GLPI-project.org](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en) does that.

Comment: I looked briefly at this and it seems to meet most of my needs, thanks! I am still exploring alternatives, though, because the documentation seems *really* spotty and the interface is somewhat cluttered. Any ideas?